# How to render .mtl file in .obj in libgdx android

Tags: android, libgdx

I've a face.obj and face.mtl file. But libgdx doesn't allow me to render face.mtl it just takes face.mtl that's why I'm not able show texture on it. So how should I load face.mtl in directly face.obj file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, LibGDX was not loading .MTL files before, and you were expected to manually load texture assets for your .OBJ model.

Now (Oct. 2012) it does. (As seen here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/71)